# Firefox not displaying SVG

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, svg

I've noticed that Firefox isn't displaying an SVG logo on this page - http://silodrome.com - It works in IE10+ as well as Chrome and Safari without any issue. The CSS being used for the logo is;

```
a#logo, a#logo:visited {
            width: 90%;
            max-width: 350px;
            margin: 45px 0 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 0;
            }

        a#logo img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            }

        a#logo:hover {
            opacity: 0.75;
            }
```

And the HTML being used on the page is;

```
<li><a href="http://silodrome.com" title="Home" id="logo"><img src="http://silodrome.com/wp-content/themes/silodrome/img/logo.svg" width="" height="" alt="Silodrome" /></a></li>
```

I've been Googling this relentlessly but I can't find a solution, any advice would be greatly appreciated, I can provide more information if needed. This is a new custom Wordpress theme.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `display:table-cell` property from `#topLinks li{...}` seems to display the svg properly in firefox but the RSS feed button gets pushed upwards !

There is nothing wrong with the SVG but the problem lies with the `display` property !

Will post a right solution soon :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Magesh, I've been researching the "display" property but not sure how to solve the RSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you've explicitly set the width and height attributes of the SVG-containing `img` to `0`. Even if you had these set to the correct sizes, using the attributes is bad practice. However, I think Firefox is ignoring this anyway; at least I can't make the image re-appear by using the dev tools to change the attributes.

I think your problem is that the SVG never reports is size. You define the `viewBox` in the SVG file, but not the image dimensions. So Firefox's `table-cell` sizing algorithm shrinks it as small as it can get: 0px × 0px.

Solutions are either to specify the size on your HTML page in CSS, or to give it the image itself a `width` or `height`. (Or, of course, do both.)